# Unable to see PnP webparts in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

For some of my users its showing error 'Something went wrong' only on the PnP webparts area. Other webparts are working fine.In the console its showing strict MIME type is checking.I am sharing the screenshot of the error along with this. If anyone have an idea about what's the cause of this issue,Please help.

[image: Here is the screenshot]

I need to show the PnP webparts to all users.